# Can someone walk me throu the angular code

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

```
webApp.factory('userAPIService', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {

    return $resource(
        "/api/reportconfig/:Id",

        {Id: "@Id" },
        {
          //  at some point change methods from GET to POST and DELETE
            "update": {method: "PUT"},
            "getreport": {'method': 'GET', 'params': {  Id:'getReportbyReportID', expire: 'true', cache:'false'}, isArray: true},
            "createreport": {'method': 'GET', 'params': { Id:'createreport', expire: 'true', cache:'false'}},
            "listreport": {'method': 'GET', 'params': { Id:'listreport', expire: 'true', cache:'false'}, isArray: true},//requre user_uuid
            "deletereport": {'method': 'GET', 'params': { Id:'deletereport', expire: 'true', cache:'false'}}
        }
    );
}]);
```

The above code get called with the following command

```
userAPIService.createreport({
                'report_config_json': report_config_json, topic_uuid: topic.uuid, report_id: reportID, user_id:userid }, {'Id': 'createreport'})
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the userAPIService actually returns when called, an object? what does it return when I call userAPIService.createreport?  How/when are the arguments passed to it?

Comment: have a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource Then continue to search on stackoverflow as this is not an uncommon question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the limited information I have above, here is what I believe is taking place in your code:

First, you are creating a factory, which is similar to a service, except you get multiple instances as opposed to a singleton (a one-time creation that every module can get via injection)

When you use the userAPIService factory in your code, you are being returned a function (which in this scenario could act like a constructor.) I can't tell without seeing the context of your use of userAPIService, but I would assume you are creating a local variable called 'userAPIService' which is being initialized to the results of a call to userAPIService().

At this point you have an instance of a userAPIService which appears to just be an data retrieval service (not to be confused with an Angular Service, which is a singleton)

your call to userAPIService.createreport() will initially return an empty object or array (noted in the docs at the bottom of this answer.) it will then make the specified $http call to the URL (from $resource definition) via the Method (from the $resource definition) and attempt to retrieve the data you are looking for. Once it has completed that request, it will then populate the reference that was just created with the actual data returned.

Since your factory creates custom actions to be taken via $resource we will look at that definition to determine what will take place when you call .createreport():

```
"createreport": {'method': 'GET', 'params': { Id:'createreport', expire: 'true', cache:'false'}}
```

This line tells $resource how to handle requests using the createreport() method. It says that when this method is called, it will make a request to the $resource object's URL via GET. It will pass default values of `expire:true` and `cache:false` as well as `Id:'createreport'` which will be used to populate the URL (Unless an Id is specified in your method call - which it is), since it requested an Id object via `:Id` at the end.

Now, when you made the actual method call, you specified two objects to pass to the $resource request, the first will then be used to basically override the default parameter values that were specified when you create the $resource method. The second will be passed as headers along with the $http request that $resource will then make.

For even more information, I would highly recommend that you read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource